# What is the meaning of "wherein" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a piece of text from the internet about the significance of the use of a Mickey Mouse theme in the movie "Full Metal Jacket":

> The singing of the Mickey Mouse  theme song at the end. This is ironic **wherein** the song is a farewell until next time, it signifies a definite
> end in the film – of life and innocence.

Can "wherein" in this example be essentially replaced by the words **"in a way that"** Is this the correct usage of this phrase?

Wherein:

> In what way; how: Wherein have we sinned? (thefreedictionary)

Comment: I find the use of _wherein_ rather odd here. I would prefer _in that_ or _in the way that_.

Comment: "Wherein" normally means "in which". It doesn't fit in your example.

Comment: "From the internet" is not a proper way to cite quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

[Lexico](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.lexico.com/definition/wherein%23:%7E:text%3Dadverb,information%2520will%2520eventually%2520be%2520used%27&ved=2ahUKEwjWsrHsmsj4AhVKxTgGHVdxBsQQFnoECA4QBQ&usg=AOvVaw0wQgoHHgTNGqnfh7n8B36_):

> In which. 'the situation wherein the information will eventually be used'

So it could be replaced with "in the way that".

> This is ironic in the way that the song is a farewell until next time, it signifies a definite end in the film – of life and innocence.